# Looking for a list of mob's attack distance for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

can I have a list of every mob's melee attack distance?  For example, a zombie can attack a mob from around 1.5 blocks away and an iron golem can attack a mob from around 2.8 blocks.

Comment: Afaik there's not a pre-existing list of this and it's not stored in nbt data as I assume you've come to find out. If no one answers this, my best advice would be to do some manual data mining and follow the first few steps of a Forge or Fabric modding tutorial to get access to the MC source code, then look through what information that has on the various entities. Second option is to manually test each entity's attack distance by incrementally teleporting it closer to something it attacks and recording what distance resulted in an attack. Neither are good options :/

Comment: I did test this out for zoglins, hoglins, and iron golems and surprisingly iron golems have a slightly higher attack distance with 2.902 blocks than zoglins/hoglins with an attack distance with 2.898

Comment: @InfinitySwordofDiamond Might it be that the distance is counted from the edge of the hitbox rather than mob's center?

Comment: I tested out for a zoglin and the player to the iron golem, but it seems like there is only a 0.1 block difference that the player gets don't get and the zoglin not getting hit.  Doesn't seem like the hitbox is really affected.  Also I teleported 2.902 blocks above and the results were the same as being in front.